# How to get a custom claim data back from Sitecore Identity server

Tags: identity-server, federated-authentication

I am working with Sitecore 9.3 and SitecoreIdentity Server 7

I have created a custom claim in an Okta authorization server called user_login, this value appears when I preview the token in the tool found in Okta. I have also set this claim to be returned in the default scope as well as a custom scope.

However when I try and get the value to pass to sitecore I cannot see it appear in the list of claims.

What do I need to add to the identity server & sitecore config files to get this value to come through? The documentation does not really provide any clear ideas on how to achieve this...

[image: Okta scope for user_login]

[image: Okta claim for user_login]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass a custom claim back to sitecore, you need to first make sure that it added to the **sitecore.profile**.  You can patch this by adding a copy of IdentityServer.xml into the relevant sub folder in sitecoreruntime folder.

Example:

```
<IdentityResources>
    <SitecoreIdentityResource>
      <Name>sitecore.profile</Name>
      <UserClaims>
        <UserClaim1>name</UserClaim1>
        <UserClaim2>email</UserClaim2>
        <UserClaim3>role</UserClaim3>
        <UserClaim4>http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/isAdmin</UserClaim4>
        <UserClaim5>http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/originalIssuer</UserClaim5>
        <UserClaim6>comment</UserClaim6>
        <UserClaim7>user_login</UserClaim7>
      </UserClaims>
      <Required>true</Required>
    </SitecoreIdentityResource>
</IdentityResources>
```

You then need to map the incoming claim from your identity provider to the claim in sitecore.profile. You do this by adding to the **ClaimsTransformations** block in the config file that defines your identity provider.

The example below is for AzureAD, but im guessing you would have something similar for Okta:

```
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <ExternalIdentityProviders>
      <IdentityProviders>
        <AzureAd type="Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders.IdentityProvider, Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders">
          <AuthenticationScheme>IdS4-AzureAd</AuthenticationScheme>
          <DisplayName>Azure AD</DisplayName>
          <Enabled>true</Enabled>
          <ClientId>xxx</ClientId>
          <TenantId>xxx</TenantId>
          <MetadataAddress></MetadataAddress>
          <ClaimsTransformations>  
            ... other claims ...
            <customClaimMapping type="Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders.DefaultClaimsTransformation, Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders">
              <SourceClaims>
                <Claim1 type="user_login" />
              </SourceClaims>
              <NewClaims>
                <Claim1 type="user_login" />
              </NewClaims>
            </customClaimMapping>
            ... other claims ...
          </ClaimsTransformations>
        </AzureAd>
      </IdentityProviders>
    </ExternalIdentityProviders>
  </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

Once you have the above setup, I then recommend using a tool such as SI Snitch to confirm exactly what claims are reaching sitecore.

SI Snitch: https://github.com/KayeeNL/SI-Snitch